# what does JavaScript 'this' in function stand for in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code below:

```
this.color = "red";
var o = {color: "blue"};
function sayColor() {
  console.log(this.color);
}
sayColor();
sayColor.call(this);
sayColor.call(o);
```

@Jim Deville,

here are the new discoveries:

1. when I run that code snippet in browser: it outputs **"red, red, blue"**, continuously.
2. when I run it directly in node terminal: it also outputs **"red, red, blue"**, continuously.
3. but when I save that code in as a file functionTypeThisExample.js, and execute `node functionTypeThisExample.js` in terminal, it outputs **"undefined, red, blue"**.

so my question is what happens in last situation?

Comment: We'd probably have to see more of the code, but it appears to be referring to the class/object itself.

Comment: you're probably right. This makes me more confused

Comment: In Node: `console.log(this === exports);`

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I tried it, then return false; ....

Comment: @Longerian Try it in a file rather than in the REPL/console. The difference for your 3rd "discovery" is that it's compiled as a [Module](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html), which sets a specific context around your script. See [`module.js`](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.6.18/lib/module.js) for more info, especially the [`_compile`](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.6.18/lib/module.js#L369) method.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski thank you, that explains a lot, I will look deep int o the module.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` in node is no different than `this` in JS. It is the object representing the current context.

`this.color = "red";`

Here, this is the global object

```
var o = {color: "blue"};
function sayColor() {
  console.log(this.color);
}

sayColor();
```

In this case, this is still the global object

`sayColor.call(this);`

This is the global object, but applied via call, not "by default"

`sayColor.call(o);`

This is `o`

When I run it in node (0.6.18 on OS X), though, I get "red, red, blue" like you do in the browser.